# Selecting the closest date from a list of records

Tags: ms-access

[image]

[image]
Hi All,

The question I have is regarding the two highlighted rows in the attached picture. The results are from a query made on two tables.

Columns 1 - 7 are from one table
Columns 8 - 13 are from another.

As you can see I have two entries for ID 1. This is because in the 2nd table there are two records relating to employee 693.

I only ever want one record per ID, the criteria is that result used from the second table should be the one that has the DateUpdated field (less than or equal to) and closest to the transactionDate in column 7.

Any ideas on how I go about doing this?

****UPDATE*****
Ok thanks to the first suggestuin my results table now looks like the 2nd picture. I have a column that shows the differences between the two dates. So how do I now get the results to only show the row with the lowest number, for each ID?

*****UPDATE********

KR

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an aggregating query with:

```
Min(Abs(DateDiff("d", [Transaction], [Date Updated]))) As NearestUpdateDate
```

and *Group By* the remaining fields.

It could go like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblEmployee.Id, 
    tblEmployee.EmployeeId, 
    tblEmployee.Transaction, 
    Min(Abs(DateDiff("d",[Transaction],[Date Updated]))) AS MinDiff
FROM 
    tblEmployee 
INNER JOIN 
    tblEmployeeWages ON 
        tblEmployee.EmployeeId = tblEmployeeWages.EmployeeId
GROUP BY 
    tblEmployee.Id, 
    tblEmployee.EmployeeId, 
    tblEmployee.Transaction;
```

Save this as `qdyEmployeeDate`. Then use this:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblEmployee.Id, 
    tblEmployee.EmployeeId, 
    tblEmployee.Transaction, 
    Min(tblEmployeeWages.[Date Updated]) AS DateUpdated
FROM 
    (tblEmployee 
INNER JOIN 
    qdyEmployeeDate ON 
        tblEmployee.Id = qdyEmployeeDate.Id) 
INNER JOIN 
    tblEmployeeWages ON 
        tblEmployee.EmployeeId = tblEmployeeWages.EmployeeId
WHERE 
    (tblEmployee.Transaction = DateAdd("d",[MinDiff],[Date Updated])) 
    OR 
    (tblEmployee.Transaction=DateAdd("d",-[MinDiff],[Date Updated]))
GROUP BY 
    tblEmployee.Id, 
    tblEmployee.EmployeeId, 
    tblEmployee.Transaction;
```

to get:

[image]

Now you have the Ids and the two dates to use. This query you can use in a new query with outer joins to the tables to retrieve the remaining fields.

Note please, that you have two employee records for 693 both having the same two update dates each having *the same date difference* to these, thus you'll get the same update date for both employee records. That you must sort out yourself.

Comment: This would just give me the differences between the dates right? Then how would I only display the rows with the lowest date? When I use this method column 13 just displays the differences between the two dates. It doesnt show only the record with the lowest difference?

Comment: Thanks very much for you help. I got a working solution from these examples.